# position and velocity control of wheeled robot

Tags: ros, pid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to control both position and velocity of a wheeled robot using ROS. Are there packages that are designed to do motion planning for this use case? Is there an example in ROS of using multiple PIDs to do something like this instead?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269980/position-and-velocity-control-of-wheeled-robot/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you only need a single PID controller. A linear model of the system might be:

x1= position,     x2= speed,      u= motor current

x1_dot = x2     (derivative of position = speed)

x2_dot = K*u   (motor speed controlled by current)

So you can control position by controlling the motor current (through integration).

Now if you want to track a path, you need to discretize it and feed in a series of position setpoints to be tracked.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-31**:
Wouldn't is just be `x2 = K*u`, as speed is controlled by current, not acceleration controlled by current? Or have I misinterpreted this?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-08-31**:
I guess that's unclear. Still only requires 1 controller, though.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-09-03**:
Depends what you/op mean by 'position'. Wheel position, as in X radians, can be done this way. But if you want to give a setpoint of world X, Y position to go to, you can't use this system. You'll need a more sophisticated controller to do that. Has OP seen [this?](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)